# Search for a string in files in subdirectories

Tags: ruby, string, file, search, directory

I need to find all strings, which contain `<some_word>`. There is MAIN directory, where we have to search and there can be files and other directroies (with files). It must enter one directory - check all files there for `<some_word>`, return to main directory - enter another directroy - check all files there, return to main directory... and so on and so for. I have no problems to make this, when there are only files in main directory... but don't know how to make it with directories... please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To process all files in a directory:

```
Dir['**/*'].each do |filepath|
  # filepath is a string path to the file or directory
  # relative from the working directory of the script
end
```

*For more information, see the documentation for [`Dir.[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) or [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob).*

Thus, if you already have `find_text_in_file( some_word, filepath )` you can do:

```
Dir['**/*'].select{|f| File.file?(f) }.each do |filepath|
  find_text_in_file( some_word, filepath )
end
```

Note that the above will search the files in a depth-first traversal. If you want to search in a breadth-first manner you can instead use this:

```
files = Dir['**/*'].select{ |f| File.file?(f) }
files.sort_by{ |f| f.split(File::SEPARATOR).length }.each do |filepath|
  find_text_in_file( some_word, filepath )
end
```

---

Alternatively, if you already have `find_word_in_directory( some_word, dirpath )` then you can do:

```
Dir['**/*'].select{ |f| File.directory?(f) }.each do |dirpath|
  find_word_in_directory( some_word, dirpath )
end
```